# Change every occurrence of a date to another format with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, replace, syntax

I'm doing my first steps with regex and I'm still a little bit confused about the syntax. I want to detect the end of sentences trough a period. I already wrote most of the rules to make this work but I still have problems with dates. 
This is my expression to change every period to a backlash in a date:

```
re.sub('\d+\.(\s)?\w+(\.)?(\s)?\d+', '\d+/\w+/\d+', text)
```

This is supposed to work with 14.8.2012 but also 14. August 2012. It seems like it recognizes the dates but it won't change them to the new format. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,
Marcel

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `text` you're working for so that we can run the code ourselves?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y54cnq8uomkeg7w/Ernst%20Abbe%20-%20Gesammelte%20Abhandlungen%20III.txt?dl=0

Comment: Learn to use backreferences. However, do you want to turn `14. August 2012` into `14/August/2012`?

Comment: Yes, the processed text doesn't need to be human readable. I just need to get stats out of it and want to process dates as one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second argument to `sub`, regex tokens like `"\d"` and `"\w"` aren't interpreted the same the way as in the regex itself.

You are replacing a date with the literal text `"\d+/\w/\d+"`. Instead, you should use

```
re.sub(r"(\d+)\.\s?(\w+)\.?\s?(\d+)", r"\1/\2/\3", text)
```

This will replace a string like `"14.8.2012"` with `"14/8/2012"` and `"14. August 2012"` with `"14/August/2012"`.

If you need the actual values (i.e. the day, month, and year), you can instead pass in a function as the second argument.

```
def replaceValues(match):
    day = match.group(1)
    month = match.group(2)
    year = match.group(3)

    # add some code here that will do something with day, month, and year

    return day + "/" + month + "/" + year

re.sub(r"(\d+)\.\s?(\w+)\.?\s?(\d+)", replaceValues, text)
```

If you want to be more specific and allow *only* months (e.g. 8, 08, Aug, August) to be accepted, you can use the code below:

```
import datetime
def replaceValues(match):
    day = match.group(1)
    month = match.group(2)
    year = match.group(3)

    # test if month is ACTUALLY a month
    formats = ['%m', '%b', '%B']
    for format in formats:
        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(month, format)
            break
        except:
            pass
    else:
        # month is not a valid month name
        return match.group(0)

    # add some code here that will do something with day, month, and year

    return day + "/" + month + "/" + year

re.sub(r"(\d+)\.\s?(\w+)\.?\s?(\d+)", replaceValues, text)
```

Comment: Such substitution may be polluted with examples from real text like: "... car #14. In 2012 I...". Perhaps datetime.strptime should be used to iterate through possible tokens to verify that the captured string is really a date.

Comment: That's true. Didn't even think of stuff like that. Thanks for the comment. I edited the answer.

Comment: Small thing about the code; rather than nested exception handling, I would suggest iterating through a list of month tokens and trying to parse as each; breaking if matched, else - considering the original string is not really a date.

Comment: My original code (I changed it to use strptime instead) would check if a month was in a list of months (['january', 'february', ... ]) but I changed it to use your suggestion of using strptime instead. I can change it back though. It also seems like using `in` would be faster than iterating through a list of months and checking if the month matches. @RebelWithoutAPulse

Comment: FIguerora: I meant something like: for token in ['%b', '%B', '%m']: datetime.strptime(month, token) break else <Indicate that this is not a month>

Comment: Ohh. Iterating through a list of month formats. I understand now. Thanks. I edited the answer again.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!